# npm ERR! at start.cmd Path must be a string - Node

Tags: node.js, npm

I can't figure why my start npm script cmd display this error on my Mac :

```
path.js:8
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' +
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:8:11)
    at Object.posix.join (path.js:479:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/romain/Desktop/Sources/com.controller.nodejs/central/app.js:16:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/romain/Desktop/Sources/com.controller.nodejs/central/bin/www:7:11)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! central@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the central@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the central package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
```

It works great on PC... The command script is

```
SET html=../../com.view.html&& npm start
```

I have the same error when running npm start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must use the `export` command instead of `set` to set an environment variable on an Unix system.

Comment: OMG you are amazing, hours I've been searching for this little trick... Thank you, I appreciate it!